# How to set up development environment for AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I wish to implement the answer that is outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50397276/1980516

However, I find that I keep running into `Unable to import module 'index'` at exactly this line:

`const   _archiver = require('archiver');`

So, I'm guessing that I cannot do this via the online console. Instead, I probably have to create a deployment package.

How do I go about this? I apparently need AWS CLI, Node.js, npm and I'm new to all of it. In the Amazon docs I can't find a practical list of how to set up my local development environment.

What tools do I install, which versions and in what order exactly?

Edit: Windows :)

Comment: What OS are you using? I can provide some more detail if I know if it's Mac, Linux, etc.

Comment: For a short quick thing, do what @noobius is suggesting i.e. zip up all your dependencies (node modules) & source (say index.js) & upload directly to Lambda using console. If the package is small (< 2MB IIRC), you can continue to edit on console. Long term, look at `AWS SAM` or `serverless` as @bwest has suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html), the Serverless Application Model. It provides a local development setup for things like Lambda functions and API Gateway endpoints, and a way to easily package and deploy things. The exact steps you need are:

1. Create an AWS account and an IAM user with admin privileges
2. Install node.js
3. Install the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) (and configure it with  `aws configure`)
4. Install [SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install.html) and Docker (the local instances run in docker containers)
5. Initialize a new SAM project with `sam init --runtime nodejs` (or other runtime version if need)
6. Run through the [quickstart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-quick-start.html) to get an idea of how to define a SAM template, build a SAM app, and deploy.

If you don't want to use the framework or local development environment and just want to create the source bundle, there are [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html). The gist is:

1. Install nodejs (e.g. using homebrew or [an installer](https://nodejs.org/en/download/))
2. `npm install` the modules you need
3. Zip up your code including the `node_modules` folder
4. Upload the zip via the AWS Console

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you need to npm install archiver and package the node_modules dependencies along with your index.js (handler file for your lambda entry point).  You can zip up and deploy/upload it to your lambda.

Also have a look at https://github.com/serverless/serverless framework, that will do these type of things easier.