# How to partially upload a ZIP file to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want my users to be able to download many files from AWS S3 bucket(potentially over few hundred GBs sized when accumulated) as one large ZIP file. I would download those selected files from S3 first and upload a newly created ZIP file on S3. This job will be rarely invoked during our service, so I decided to use Lambda for it.

But Lambda has its own limitations - 15 min of execution time, ~500MB `/tmp` storage, etc. I found several workaround solutions on Google that can beat the storage limit(streaming) but found no way to solve execution time limit.

Here are what I've found so far:

- https://dev.to/lineup-ninja/zip-files-on-s3-with-aws-lambda-and-node-1nm1
- [Create a zip file on S3 from files on S3 using Lambda Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633577/create-a-zip-file-on-s3-from-files-on-s3-using-lambda-node/50397276#50397276)

Note that programming language is not a concern here.

Could you please give me a suggestion?

Comment: Don't use lambda? Seams rather obvious that lambda is not the good match for your requirement.

Comment: @Marcin running a separate EC2 instance would fit better for this kind of job? I'm considering about the cost, too.

Comment: ec2 instance or docker on fargate. These are possibilities worth checking out. Have to investigate their advantages/disadvantages for your scenario and decide if its worth pursing lambda solution. Lambda is not a golden solution for every possible use case.

Comment: @Marcin thanks, I'll check those options!